# Selenium chrome driver hangs while using action.dragAndDrop ( waiting for physical mouse movment )

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, drag-and-drop, testng-eclipse

I am trying to use drag and drop action on this site https://app.involve.me/

The steps I am doing are :

1. login to the site
2. creating a new project from scratch
3. Try to drag and drop an item from the list on the right side( no matter what item).
   every time I drag item selenium will hang until I move my physical mouse and only then
   selenium will continue the test

I use TestNG with selenium 4.3.0

[selenium hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNeIP.png)

**my code:**

public void dragAndDropCleanPage(String imageName) {

```
    try {
        WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='e-target-dropzone vcentered bgfixed center-center']"));
        List<WebElement> listOfImages = imageList;
        for(WebElement el : listOfImages ) {
            WebElement text = el.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='v-title'] p"));
            if(getText(text).equalsIgnoreCase(imageName)){
                WebElement drag = el;
                Actions act = new Actions(driver);
                act.clickAndHold(drag)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .moveToElement(to)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .moveByOffset(0,1)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .release(to)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .build().perform();
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Did not find the requested item");
    }
```

this is the loop I use to pick the right item by name ( I use pageFactory for finding elements )

I tried all solutions - action drag and drop javascript executer, etc...

if someone will be able to solve my problem it will be great
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who needs a solution, you can use:

```
action.moveToElement(element);

action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).click().build().perform();
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved your problem.